# How can I assign an accelerator key to LXDE's start menu's Run?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, lxde

I use LXDE (as part of Lubuntu 15.04). When I press <kbd>Win</kbd>, I get the 'Start menu', which has a 'Run' entry. I would like to press <kbd>r</kbd> and have that entry selected... but <kbd>r</kbd> currently does nothing. How can I set that as an accelerator key for the Run entry?